# How find "circumflex" in Notepad++ for Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to do a regex to ignore html colors, I tried this:

> ([a-z0-9A-Z]{7})

But I don't know how to add "circumflex" ahead.
Someone could help me?

Examples of the codes:

```
^FF0000
^FFFFFF
^777777
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by circumflex? If you want to match the `^`, you need to escape it with a backslash

Comment: I did it: `(\^[a-z0-9A-Z]{6})` and worked very well, thank you very much.

Comment: , You should not include 'thank' in posts. See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: I didn't know that "caret" is the same thing that "circumflex", english isn't my native language, I searched for circumflex and I didn't find nothing about my doubt then I've asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

> (\^[a-z0-9A-Z]{7})

[image: Notepad++ screenshot]